# query on bitwise ANDing after bitwise ORing

Tags: bit-manipulation

I came across a code snippet where `AND-ing` a value with all 1's is made after `OR-ing` the value with a number. For example:

```
value|=0x100;
value &=0xFFFF;
```

Why is the `AND-ing` required? I believe no matter if we do the `AND-ing` or not, the value in status remains same after `OR-ing`. But trying to understand the intention of `AND-ing` with all 1's again.

Comment: Is that really "all 1's" though? How many bits are in `value`?

Answer (score 0):

The ANDing is probably copy pasted from some other code where it made a difference. The intention is to keep the result to 16 bits, its like an assembler programmers typecast to 16 bits. Very useful if the result of the operation becomes negative.